# Inheritance query in a VIEW without the need for UNION (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-performance, sqlperformance

In SQL Server, I have the following VIEW:

```
CREATE VIEW product_product_price_inheritance AS
SELECT 
    sub_product.product_id,
    sub_product_price.sub_product_id,
    sub_product_price.currency_id,
    sub_product_price.pricing_tier_id,
    sub_product_price.price
FROM cms_module_product_product_sub_product_price sub_product_price
INNER JOIN cms_module_product_product_sub_product sub_product ON sub_product_price.sub_product_id = sub_product.id

UNION

SELECT 
    product_price.product_id,
    sub_product.id as sub_product_id,
    product_price.currency_id,
    product_price.pricing_tier_id,
    product_price.price
FROM cms_module_product_product_price product_price
LEFT OUTER JOIN cms_module_product_product_sub_product sub_product ON product_price.product_id = sub_product.product_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM cms_module_product_product_sub_product_price sub_product_price
    WHERE sub_product_price.sub_product_id = sub_product.id 
    AND sub_product_price.currency_id = product_price.currency_id
    AND sub_product_price.pricing_tier_id = product_price.pricing_tier_id
)
```

The query applies product pricing to it's sub products (e.g. variations like size, colour) if no pricing is set directly for the sub product.

We use this VIEW to join to other queries to get inherited pricing.

Because of the UNION, we can't apply any indexes to the VIEW.

Is there a better way to rewrite this query to avoid using the UNION at all? So we can apply indexes and get better performance when joining to it?

Comment: Could you convert it into a stored procedure where the results are added to a temp table for output? Then each of the separate queries could be outfitted with appropriate indexes. You'd lose the ability to query it like the view affords, but perhaps with stored procedure parameters?

Comment: This can probably be done but this is so hard to decipher since everything is underscores and lower case. You would need to provide a [mcve] for any real help.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be a big help.